# Get all Facebook links with the same URL

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to retrieve the IDs of all links shared on Facebook that have the same URL?

For example, I want to retrieve all the shared links that have the URL http://www.google.com and get their IDs so I can get all the comments for the said URL.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible. There are a couple of issues. First, you can't see comments or posts that are not 'visible' to the user account you are making the request with. Second, there simply isn't any api method to do a query like this. You will have to query pages or profiles that you have access to to find these shares.